# JavaScript TypeError when indexing into 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on some code that manipulates a 2D array of "cell" objects.

```
function randomDestFromStart(cell, temp)
{
    function addPossible(x, y)
    {
        var test1 = temp[x];
        var test2 = test1[y];  // This line
        // ... //
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < temp[0].length; i++)
        addPossible(cell.x, i);

    // ... //
}
```

`temp` is the 2d array, and `cell` is a particular Cell object. Defining `test2` results in the following error:

```
TypeError: test1 is undefined
```

I have confirmed in the debugger that `x` and `y` are valid integers (in this particular case they are 0 and 1 respectively). `temp` is a valid array consisting of 5 subarrays of Cell objects, so there shouldn't be any sort of index out of bounds error. There doesn't seem to be an issue indexing one level into `temp` seeing as `test1` is a valid array of 5 cells (essentially a row of `temp`). The problem is when I index into the 2nd dimension of the array, which is strange since indexing into the same exact array works in other parts of the code.

EDIT: The problem seems to be with the inputs for x and y. When I hardcode these values everything works fine. For example, `addPossible(2, 3)` works. The error occurs when the values are provided dynamically, but this is strange because the debugger shows x and y as completely normal and valid integers even in these cases. I am 99% sure this is NOT an out of bounds issue. I have checked and the array is 5x5, and x and y are always between 0 and 4.

Comment: Please show the content of the array. We can't tell you what is going on without seeing the data you are trying to read from.

Comment: Shouldn't you not have the first level array index hard coded to 0, for your iteration loop? "i < tmp[0].length"

Comment: Could you insert `console.log(temp)` in the very beginning of `addPossible` definition and tell us what it will say?

Comment: @winterblood the array is a bit large to post. It is a 5x5 array of cell objects, I have confirmed that via the debugger.

Comment: What if we check `console.log(typeof x)`?

Comment: @Dmitry unfortunately the output is "number" (I was hoping that would reveal an issue :( ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your temp array is larger than whatever value exists in cell.x. Its also possible that cell.x is one too big and you want cell.x -1

Comment: Yup, turns out it was out of bounds after all. I must've been reading Firebug wrong the whole time because I never saw a value that was too big. Using `console.log(x)` solved the problem.